# Bind a function on multiple jQuery elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 3 jquery objects:

```
var a = $('.el1');
var b = $('.el2');
var c = $('.el3');
```

And I want to bind a "change" event to all of them at once, but I can't :(

`$(a, b, c).bind('paste input change', function(){ ... });` simply doesn't work...

But if bind it to each element separately it works:

```
a.bind('...');
b.bind('...');
c.bind('...');
```

Is it possible to do this in a shorter way?

(And without passing the classes as selectors)

Comment: Have you tried `$('.el1, .el2, .el3').bind`?

Comment: yes and I know it works, but I don't want to do that because the objects are used in other places and I don't like to work with classes trough the entire script. I like to use them only at the beginning :) (eg. in case I change the classes I don't have to search the all script)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`.add()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
a.add(b).add(c).bind(...
```

Comment: tx, that was what I needed :D

Answer (score 6):

$([a,b,c]).bind should work, as in:

```
var a = $('.el1');
var b = $('.el2');
var c = $('.el3');

$([a,b,c]).each(function(idx){
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.el1, .el2, .el3').bind(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('.el1, .el2, .el3').bind(....`.

Another solution is to combine them later:

```
var d = a;
d.add(b);
d.add(c);

d.bind(....
```

And if you don't like that either, if you would call the separate binds after all, you can choose to declare a named function once, and refer to that, instead of declaring the same anonymous inline function three times.

Comment: does the function really get declared 3 times?

Comment: Well, there's probably some optimization to prevent that, but it would at least be parsed three times and checked against a hash of existing functions to see if it's the same.

Comment: A common mistake with the `.add()` method is that it does NOT add the element to the current jQuery object.  It returns a new jQuery object with it added.  So you need `d = d.add(b)` to add `b` to `d`.